# What kind of Matrix Transformation is this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Sorry if this is a very basic question, but I have been given a task to type a program in which I am supposed to convert square matrices into 4 different forms. I understand that one of them is a simple transpose of the matrix, but I don't get what transformations are the other three?

Can anyone please explain the logic behind these transformations, or provide the name of them so that I can study them on my own? Thank you!
[image: Please Click Here for the Image, it's an Imgur Link]

If you don't want to see the image then please see the following,

the sample matrix is as follows,

```
10   2   6
4   20   0
8   0   30
```

First transformation is as follows,

```
0   0   2
4   6   8
10   20   30
```

Second transformation is as follows (the way I understand, it is simply the reverse of first transformation)

```
30   20   10
8   6   4
2   0   0
```

Third transformation is as follows (clearly a transpose)

```
10   4   8
2   20   0
6   0   30
```

Fourth transformation is as follows (the way I understand, they simply have replaced all the diagonal entries with 1 while the other entries remain same as before)

```
1   2   6
4   1   0
8   0   1
```

Comment: they do not have a name (except for the transposition). The exercise is clearly intented to let you practice by implementing transformations where you permute the elements in some arbitrary way

Comment: The second one is an interchange of the first and the last rows/columns (hence a similarity transform by a reversal matrix), but I agree with Exodd: the exercise don't seem to be motivated by linear algebra considerations.

Comment: The first and second transformation are an ascending and descending sort of the entries of the matrix followed by a "reshaping" of the result into a $3 \times 3$ array. This could be written as a one line statemant in Matlab.